# Calculate real world coordinates given camera intrisinc, extrinsic, trimesh

Tags: python, camera, trimesh, extrinsic-parameters, camera-intrinsics

I am struggling to map pixel coordinates to world coordinates. From what i've found on google, apparently I have to use the camera intrinsic/extrinsic (I have them).

Can you explain me how to use the rotation matrix & the translation vector to map from pixel to realworld? **I am using the camera settings from trimesh**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For a standard camera you can only map each pixel to a ray starting from the optical center of the camera. If you want to have a 3D-point you need additional information, e.g. a real-world plane which is intersected by the ray.